# What approach should I take if my feature value changes after the initial prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

**Goal** -
Predict number of days the finished good would be delayed from a promised date of delivery?

**Background** -
It is only 7 weeks before the promised date of delivery that the demand becomes proxy final. Meaning there can be a change in Qty/promised date of delivery/both in the 7 weeks period (run up to promise date of delivery)

**Challenge**-
If my prediction point is (Promised Date of Delivery - 7 weeks). It is likely that some of the feature value might change in the 7 weeks period.

**Question** - What approach or how do I cater if the following happens after my initial prediction?

1. Qty changes (new qty < initial qty), after my prediction? - *Scenario -I*
2. Promise date of delivery is moved further? *Scenario -II*
3. Both the qty changes and promise date of delivery is moved further? *Scenario -III*

If I have a secondary model for the following scenarios :

a. How would I cater for the 3rd change, will it be catered by my
second model?

b. What will be the composition of the training set?
Training Set Model I - Initial state of the demand
Training Set Model II - Second State of demand +3rd State of
demand.. + Nth State of Demand

or

Do I need a different approach to tackle this problem and what would it be?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should just do a new prediction with this new/updated data. Of course it depends if you have included this features in the data set yet ? You could include features like nb of changes already done yet ... But please give details about your features and model.

Comment: @Malo - I have added more information to the question, hope this gives more context. I have thought of adding the feature, but not sure if it would be sufficient based on the dynamic nature of the process.

Comment: @Jon Nordby I had gone through your answer in [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/predict-how-many-days-late-or-early-someone-will-finish-their-work) . The problem is on the similar lines. I was wondering if you had any advise on the best way to tackle this? Thanks

Comment: You shoud focus on:
* only 1 model: it seems you do not need to have more if proper features are used
* more features like: initial quantity, replanned quatity, delta qualtity, initial delay,  replanned delay, delay delta, nb of replanning, company/team workload, holidays periods, nb of employees ...
* gather data about past real cases

Comment: @Malo Thanks. But what would be my point of prediction in the above process? If I make the prediction seven weeks prior to date, the variables such as replanned quantity, replanned delay would be zero. Are you suggesting to recalculate if there is a change in the feature value and have a fresh prediction?

Comment: with the added features, you can run the prediction anytime, so you have only one model for all cases. Of course for the very first prediction you will have 0 delay/Replanned. But when you need to rerun the model later this number will increase and be taken into account by the model (but you have have to track these numbers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129514/discussion-between-jas999-and-malo).